# I am trying to implement Vue data into a Bootstrap carousel

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-carousel

The first slide works perfect, but the second slide won't load the Vue data into the slide.  I can't use Vue slick carousel or array functions since the carousel has so many objects. It also breaks if I try to separate them into their own sections within the data.  I included my code below.  I'm out of ideas and could use yours.

```
''' <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" id="books_pg">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Books</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredericka+the+Great&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main_boot.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <span id="header"></span>

    <main>
        <div class=" container">
            <div class="row"></div>
            <div id="bookSeries" class="carousel slide" data-interval="0" data-ride="carousel">
                <div  class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active timeBooks" >
                        <div v-html="t105.bkCover" class="row"></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="container d-flex">
                                <div class="wrapper row ml-15 justify-content-center">
                                    <a class="trailer col-sm-12 col-md-2" :href="t105.link"><h2 class="text-bottom">trailer</h2></a>
                                    <p class="sum col-md-7">{{t105.sum}}</p>
                                    <a  class="meme col-sm-12 col-md-2" href="meme.html"> <h2>memes</h2></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item timeBooks">
                        <div v-html="t205.bkCover" class="row"></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="container d-flex">
                                <div class="wrapper row ml-15 justify-content-center">
                                    <a class="trailer col-sm-12 col-md-2" :href="t205.link"><h2 class="text-bottom">trailer</h2></a>
                                    <p class="sum col-md-7">{{t205.sum}}</p>
                                    <a  class="meme col-sm-12 col-md-2" href="meme.html"> <h2>memes</h2></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <a class="controller carousel-control-prev" href="#bookSeries" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="controller carousel-control-next" href="#bookSeries" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <div class="row justify-items-center">
        <a><h6 id="off">Off the Rails books</h6></a>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="includes row">
            <span id="ft"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

</body>
</html>'''

'''const Test = new Vue({
    el: '.timeBooks',
    data: {
        t105: {
            bkCover:
                '<img class="cover d-block col-md-2 mx-auto mt-2 img-fluid" src="img/books/time105am.png" alt="1:05 A.M. cover">',

            sum: "At the beginning of a new ice era, past and present will collide, and love will survive the ice and snow that encases the planet.\n" +
                "                                        Karmen-Marie has spent the last decade working for her father’s shady business as an assassin. Once underground she must hunt and kill her mysterious target.\n" +
                "                                        Rea, a second-generation military trained instructor. Build, train, and move on, is the only way of life Rea understands.\n" +
                "                                        Rea’s former flame has come to kill him. An accidental mix-up causes the killer to loses her memory. Rae struggles to let this attractive hired gun back into his heart.",
            link: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTgiOKYp-9s&feature=youtu.be',
            meme: '\meme.html',
             },
        t205: {
            bkCover:
                '<img class="cover d-block col-md-2 mx-auto mt-2 img-fluid" src="img/books/time205am.jpg" alt="2:05 A.M. cover">',

            sum: "class=\"sum col-sm-12 col-md-8 mr-3\"> After spending all her life trying to be normal, Nova gives up. Content in her private world and with no desire to change, she finds herself pulled into a mission that takes her away from her safe and secluded life.\n" +
                "                        Arrow has been trapped in a cage for, well, he can’t recall, but he is ready to be free. When his “Angel” appears, she’s what he’s been searching for all his life, and his soul knows her. But his angel doesn’t know who he is, nor does she care, and she resists helping him.\n" +
                "                        Before long they will uncover the dark past that haunts Arrow, and the even darker future that awaits them both.",
            link: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ug2VqdaFmZY',
            meme: '\meme.html',
             },
    }
})''''''
```

Answer (score 0):

I have built several Vue 2 apps utilizing Bootstrap, but hadn't used the Carousel, so it sounded like an interesting exercise.

I have a Vue CLI sandbox app that I use for testing functionality, so I created a Single File Component based on your code above, started editing and building, but ultimately decided to start with a simpler component. I created an SFC from the Bootstrap Carousel example in the documentation.  I suggest that you simplify your code until you get the carousel working as well.

Once I made sure that I imported Bootstrap and jQuery in my main.js (again, using Vue CLI), the simplified carousel is working.  Here is the code from my Carousel.vue component.  I may do some additional work to implement a 'v-for' loop for the carousel items, but wanted to get this posted.

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="carousel">
        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <h4>{{ slideData[0].title }}</h4>
              <img class="d-block w-100" :src="slideData[0].imgSrc" :alt="slideData[0].title">
              <p>{{ slideData[0].text }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <h4>{{ slideData[1].title }}</h4>
              <img class="d-block w-100" :src="slideData[1].imgSrc" :alt="slideData[1].title">
              <p>{{ slideData[1].text }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <h4>{{ slideData[2].title }}</h4>
              <img class="d-block w-100" :src="slideData[2].imgSrc" :alt="slideData[2].title">
              <p>{{ slideData[2].text }}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        slideData: [
          {
            id: 1,
            title: 'First slide',
            text: `The carousel is a slideshow for cycling through a series of content,
             built with CSS 3D transforms and a bit of JavaScript. It works with a series of images,
              text, or custom markup. It also includes support for previous/next controls and indicators.`,
            imgSrc: require('../../assets/images/my-portrait.jpg')
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Second slide',
            text: `In browsers where the Page Visibility API is supported, the carousel will avoid sliding
             when the webpage is not visible to the user (such as when the browser tab is inactive, the browser
              window is minimized, etc.).`,
            imgSrc: require('../../assets/images/my-portrait.jpg')
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            title: 'Third slide',
            text: `Please be aware that nested carousels are not supported, and carousels are generally not
             compliant with accessibility standards.`,
            imgSrc: require('../../assets/images/my-portrait.jpg')
          }
        ]

      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me.